# PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter and Save taking more than a minute to write a file

Tags: php, excel-2007

Below is my code. I'm getting the data as a string with 2 parts. First part is all about headers for an excel sheet. And the 2nd part is about the actual data. They are separated by a special delimiter.

Again the second part (actual data) is separated with '\n' for each row with each column again divided with delimiter '|'.

Now if i click on download, the excel is being generated after 1 min 20 secs.. Please help me finding the culprit as I'm new to php.

Im using PHPExcel_IOFactory plugin here..

if (!empty($json_decodeArr))
        $dataExists = 1;
    else
        $dataExists = 0;

```
$service_name = $params['service_name'];
$company_name = $params["company_name"];
    $language = $params["language"];

$cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_to_phpTemp;
$cacheSettings = array(' memoryCacheSize ' => '32MB');
PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod, $cacheSettings);

// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

if (isset($GLOBALS[$service_name]["TEMPLATE_NAME"]) && $GLOBALS[$service_name]["TEMPLATE_NAME"] != '') {
    $template = $GLOBALS[$service_name]["TEMPLATE_NAME"];
    $ext = $GLOBALS[$service_name]["TEMPLATE_NAME_EXT"];
    $path = $GLOBALS[$service_name]["TEMPLATE_PATH"];
    $filepath = $path . $template.$language . "." . $ext;
    try {
        //load Excel template file
        $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($filepath);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        die('Error loading file ' . $e -> getMessage());
    }

} else {
    $template = $GLOBALS["TEMPLATE_BLANK"];
    $ext = $GLOBALS[$service_name]["TEMPLATE_BLANK_EXT"];
    $path = $GLOBALS["TEMPLATE_BLANKPATH"];
    $filepath = $path . $template . "." . $ext;
    try {
        //load Excel template file
        $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($filepath);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        die('Error loading file ' . $e -> getMessage());
    }
}

$temp_array = array();

//Named Configuration XLS Generation


//Writing Values into the excel sheet
$counter = 0;
$objPHPExcel -> setActiveSheetIndex(1);
$currentSheet = $objPHPExcel -> getActiveSheet();


foreach ($json_decodeArr as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == 0) {

        $headerNamesArr = explode("|",$GLOBALS[$service_name][$template][0]["HeaderNames"]);
        $headerExcelPositionArr = explode("|",$GLOBALS[$service_name][$template][0]["HeaderExcelPosition"]);
        $headerDataArr = explode("|",$value);
        foreach ($headerNamesArr as $headerName) {  
            $headerData = getHeaderValue($headerName,$headerDataArr);
            $currentSheet -> setCellValue(getHeaderValue($headerName,$headerExcelPositionArr), $headerData);                    
        }
        //file_put_contents("testResponse.txt", getHeaderValue('daysleft:',$headerDataArr));
    } else {

        //$activeWS = "B";
        $index = $GLOBALS[$service_name][$template][0]["ROW_START"];

        //file_put_contents("testResponse.txt", $GLOBALS[$service_name][$template][0]["COL_START"]);

        $rows = explode("\n", $value);

        foreach ($rows as $values1) {
            $activeWS = $GLOBALS[$service_name][$template][0]["COL_START"];
            $rowData = explode("|", $values1);
            //file_put_contents("testResponse.txt",$rowData);
            foreach ($rowData as $vals) {
                $WSName = $activeWS . $index;
                $currentSheet -> setCellValue($WSName, $vals);
                $activeWS++;
            }
            $index++;

        }
        $counter++;
    }
}

//$objPHPExcel->removeSheetByIndex($rowStart);
$objPHPExcel -> setActiveSheetIndex(0);

// Redirect output to a client.s web browser (Excel5)
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=" . $filename . ".xlsx");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
// If you"re serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header("Cache-Control: max-age=1");

// If you"re serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
// Date in the past
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
// always modified
header("Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate");
// HTTP/1.1
header("Pragma: public");
// HTTP/1.0

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, "Excel2007");
unset($objPHPExcel);
ob_start(); 
$objWriter -> save("php://output");
ob_flush();
exit ;
```

Comment: Why `unset($objPHPExcel);`?

Comment: @MarkBaker to save memory, PHPExcel is heavy on memory and when storing the output in cache with ob_start you want as much process memory available as possible, especially if you are working with large files.

Comment: And for OP, how big is your data set? if there is a lot of data an you are running on a slow machine generating Excel files can take quite some time. If it is not a large set of data, try revising all of your iterations as you have quite a lot of them.

Comment: XLS is working fine with a max of 4 secs to download, but XLSX is taking more than 75secs

Comment: You do realise that simply unsetting a PHPExcel object won't work, it won't unset because of cyclic references ([as documented](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/05-Deleting-a-Workbook.md)).... and the object is also required for the call to the writers `save()` method.... so trying to unset it accomplishes precisely nothing but a cost in CPU cycles